# assertHeader fails

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, controller, phpunit

Can anyone tell me why assertHeader and assertHeaderContains fail for me? Everything else works fine.

I have a response object that is clearly returning valid data (see below). I'm running some basic controller unit-tests against this response, all of which work, except for "assertHeader" and "assertHeaderContains".

Here's a dump of my Zend_Http_Response, without the body. This response is returned by a controller method (customer/read):

```
.object(Zend_Http_Response)#182 (5) {
["version":protected]=>
string(3) "1.1"
["code":protected]=>
int(200)
["message":protected]=>
string(2) "OK"
["headers":protected]=>
array(8) {
["Connection"]=>
string(5) "close"
["Date"]=>
string(29) "Thu, 27 Jan 2011 14:30:07 GMT"
["Server"]=>
string(17) "Microsoft-IIS/6.0"
["X-powered-by"]=>
string(7) "ASP.NET"
["X-aspnet-version"]=>
string(9) "2.0.50727"
["Cache-control"]=>
string(7) "private"
["Content-type"]=>
string(8) "text/xml"
["Content-length"]=>
string(4) "2075"
}
["body":protected]=>
```

Here's my unit tests:

```
public function testCustomerRead(){       
    $this->dispatch('customer/read'); // works
    $this->assertResponsecode(200); // works
    $this->assertController('customer'); // works
    $this->assertAction('read'); // works

    // FAILS with: Failed asserting response header "Content-type" found**
    $this->assertHeader('Content-type'); 

    **// FAILS with: Failed asserting response header "Content-type" exists and contains "text/xml"** 
    $this->assertHeaderContains('Content-type', 'text/xml'); 
}
```

Comment: The Zend_Http_Response object dump that is provided was made in testCustomerRead() just after  $this->dispatch('customer/read');?

Answer (score 3):

Give a try to 'Content-Type'.
Something like that:

```
$this->assertHeaderContains('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Comment: Hi. I too am trying to get assertHeader working. I've checked my spelling of 'Content-Type' and opened the api in the browser with firebug to see if the header is present (which it is). Still it is failing. Like the person who posted this question, all others are passing (responseCode, controller etc)